# Проверка символов/чисел считанных из текстового файла

Tags: c++

Возник вопрос, считываю массив из файла и сортирую его таким образом:

```
            ifstream file("input.txt");

            if (!file.is_open()) 
                cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!"<<endl; 
            else
            {
                int n, count = 0;
                while (file >> n) ++count;

                file.clear();
                file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

                int * data = new int[count];
                int * sort_data = new int[count];
                count = 0;
                while (file >> n) data[count++] = n;

                cout << "Массив из файла:" << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    cout << data[i] << ' ';
                cout << endl;


                ////////////////////////////////////
                sort_mass(data, count);
                ////////////////////////////////////


                cout << "Отсортированный массив значений: " << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    cout << data[i] << " ";
                cout << endl;
```

Как выполнить проверку на сторонние символы, чтобы если в файле находится, что-то не в таком виде: -3 15 5 10 16, выдать сообщение об ошибке чтения либо выделить из записанного именно числа и записать их в массив

Comment: Отформатируйте код

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, в вашей текущей программе, если встретится что-то, отличное от целого числа, оператор >> переведет поток в невалидное состояние и цикл while (первый) прервется. Вам надо лишь отличить эту ситуацию от нормального конца файла (eof()). Но вы не узнаете, что конкретно не так и не сможете продолжить чтение. Если вы хотите более универсальный вариант, то можно делать так:

- считывать из файла строки (std::string);
- пробовать сконвертить в целое число (например, std::stoi);
- если удалось - принимать число в обработку, иначе - выводить
  сообщение об ошибке и продолжать дальше;

При таком подходе можно прочитать весь файл, обработать все корректные числа и поругаться на все некорректные.

И, кстати, если вы вместо динамического массива будете использовать вектор (std::vector), вы сможете все сделать все за один проход (то есть, считывать строку, преобразовывать в число, если все ОК, класть в вектор), ибо вектор автоматически увеличивает размер при необходимости.